# how to get input group radio value from input text box

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I need to store the input fields with selected ones, how can I be able to do that with help of jQuery, Javascript, any idea?

```
<div class="input-group">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <div class="input-group-text">
    <input type="radio" name="choosen">
    </div>
  </div>
 <input type="text"  name="opt[]"  />
  <br />
</div>

<div class="input-group">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <div class="input-group-text">
    <input type="radio" name="choosen">
    </div>
  </div>
   <input type="text"  name="opt[]"  />
  <br />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the input field value, by clicking on the radio button.
Make sure you add something on the input field, before click on the radio button. Checkout the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/5L87pfn3)

```js
$('input[type=radio]').on('click', function() {

  var inputValue = $('input[type=radio]:checked').closest('.input-group').find('input[type=text]').val(); /* You can use let instead of var */

  console.log(inputValue);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <div class="input-group-text">
      <input type="radio" name="choosen">
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="text" name="opt[]" />
  <br />
</div>

<div class="input-group">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <div class="input-group-text">
      <input type="radio" name="choosen">
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="text" name="opt[]" />
  <br />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on a few things:

## Where do you want to store?

If you intend to store it in the browser, then you can use `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` to do so. If you want to store it on the server, then you will need to send it somehow, maybe as form data, or an AJAX request, or via WebSocket.

## When do you want to invoke the store?

If you want to invoke the store upon each value change, then you could add a `change` event, like:

```
let options = document.querySelectorAll("input[name=choosen]");
for (let option of options) {
    option.addEventListener('change', function() {
        storeCheckedOption(options);
    });
}
```

So far, so good. Now let's implement `storeCheckedOption`:

```
function storeCheckedOption(options) {
    for (let option of options) {
        if (option.checked) {
            store("choosen", option.value);
            return;
        }
    }
    store("choosen", "");
}
```

Now let's implement `store`. For now I assume that you intend to store it into `localStorage`, but you can change the way things are stored in the way you intend:

```
function store(key, value) {
    localStorage.[(value ? "set" : "remove") + "Item"](key, value);
}
```

Naturally, you can do this with AJAX as well if you intend to store it on server-side.

However, if you want to store the chosen radio button on the server when the form is being submitted, then you do not need to do anything on the client-side. Instead, you can parse the request parameters on server-side and store the chosen item there.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code :)

```js
var store;

$('button').on('click', function(){
    let value = $('input[type=radio]:checked').parents('.input-group').find('input[type=text]').val();
  store = value;
  
  console.log(store);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <div class="input-group-text">
    <input type="radio" name="choosen">
    </div>
  </div>
 <input type="text"  name="opt[]"  />
  <br />
</div>

<div class="input-group">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <div class="input-group-text">
    <input type="radio" name="choosen">
    </div>
  </div>
   <input type="text"  name="opt[]"  />
  <br />
</div>
<br>
<button>Store</button>
```